# boto simpledb doesn't support desc sorts? or I'm confused

Tags: python, boto, amazon-simpledb

It seems to my that python's boto doesn't support DESC sorts.  For example:

```
conn.create_domain('testing')

dom = conn.get_domain('testing')

dom.put_attributes ('hulk', { 'color': 'green', 'strength' : 90 })
dom.put_attributes ('iron man', { 'color': 'yellow', 'strength' : 50 })
dom.put_attributes ('me', { 'purple': 'blue', 'strength' : 1 })
dom.put_attributes ('superman', { 'color': 'red', 'strength' : 100 })
dom.put_attributes ('captain america', { 'color': 'blue', 'strength' : 10 })

q = dom.select ("select * from testing where strength is not null order by strength desc", consistent_read=True, max_items=1)
for r in q:
    print "strongest is " + str(r.name) + " " + r['strength']

conn.delete_domain('testing')
```

the result is:

```
strongest is hulk 90
```

Well either boto or SimpleDB was coded by a hardcore Marvel fan, or I'm not understanding something, because that should not be the result.

Now if I switch it to "order by strength asc" I get:

```
strongest is me 1
```

So it seems like sorting works correctly if you ascend, but not if you descend?

I'm trying to simulate the equivalent of a SQL MAX() function, which SimpleDB's SELECT syntax doesn't support.

BTW, the actual dataset is, alas, much less colorful.

Comment: Knowing nothing about `boto`, I suspect it's storing it as chars... can you `sort by strength + 0 asc` & `sort by strength + 0 desc` ?

Comment: You win! All SimpleDB sorts are done in lex order.  Grrrrr. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/SortingDataSelect.html

Comment: Yeah, [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/SDB_API_PutAttributes.html) states that Attribute.X.Value is always a string. Well, the drawbacks from _simple_ I imagine..